# Development Process with Continuous Integration Servers

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, proget

I'm pretty new to using continuous integration within a normal development process as a developer. However i've been task to introduce ci into our software team and have therefore made some attempts to accomplish this.

Currently we have the following:
0. BitBucket as our source repo
1. Team City
2. ProGet server
3. Octopus Deploy
4. Developement testing vm
5. UAT testing vm
6. Production vm

In general the process goes

1. List item
2. Check out solution from BitBucket
3. Make Changes.
4. Commit to Bitbucket
5. Team City Builds
6. Team City pushes artifacts to ProGet as nuget packages
7. Team City creates release in Octopus Deploy and trigger auto deployment to the Development Test vm.
8. Manual Octopus push to UAT
9. Manual Octopus push to Production

Everything from the top level looks fine for everyone except us developers.

Our problem is not the concept but the living with the process. The reason is that we have two solutions where the second references a nuget package of the first solution from our ProGet server. What this means is that every time the dependant solution need a modification in the first solution we have to wait for the cycle to occur and then  update the nuget package in the second to complete the required changes.

This gets really frustrating when this cycle needs to occur many time before the required outcome is achieved.

What i would love is to develop both solution on the developer's pc without the need to wait for the ci to build and publish the changed package. This i think means the dll from the first solution to be referenced locally but how can i change this so the final reference is fromt he ProGet server to be built on the CI box?

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

This workflow can get quite challenging; we're seeing a lot of users migrating to a more Infrastructure-as-Code approach.

Consider this tutorial [Deploying ASP.NET and Windows Service Applications with Otter](http://inedo.com/support/tutorials/deploying-aspnet-and-windows-service-applications-with-otter) -- the idea is, that building the solution via MSBuild (either in Release mode on your workstation, or in TeamCity) creates a package file (UPack or NuGet, doesn't matter).

Then, as a developers, you can add a step to use [Otter Romp](http://inedo.com/support/documentation/otter/reference/romp) to configure/deploy that package locally, and regular [Otter](http://inedo.com/otter) to ensure the package/configuration exists in other environments. This way, it's a consistent approach across local to dev to test to prod.

Anyway this describes a very different approach, so it may not be a great answer to your question, but you asked about a process change so this is one I've been seeing a lot.

See also: [KB#1114 - A Comparison: Octopus Deploy vs Otter](http://inedo.com/support/kb/1114/a-comparison-octopus-deploy-vs-otter)

__

Disclaimer, my day job is at Inedo :)